# c3p0 database pooling Statement close FAILED. java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection

Tags: oracle, c3p0, mule-esb

I am newbie to Java and c3p0 database pooling. We have build api on mulesoft and deployed to cloudhub (vpc + vpn config), the application connects to database on premise.

The application logs shows below warning about connection closed every 12 hours (exactly)

```
16:59:32.799     07/28/2021     Worker-0     C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->|41d2c93]-HelperThread-#2     WARN
Statement close FAILED.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.needLine(PhysicalConnection.java:3525)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.closeOrCache(OracleStatement.java:1478)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.close(OracleStatement.java:1461)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.close(OracleStatementWrapper.java:122)
    at com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(DefaultConnectionTester.java:325)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:510)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:464)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishIdleResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:436)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:2211)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

If a request is received within last few minutes reaching 12 hr time then it fails with 500 error  `connection.ConnectionException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out`

I have configured spring based datasource and here is my configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"


xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">



<bean id="oracle-jdbcdatasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${oracle.host}:${oracle.port}/${oracle.database}"/>
<property name="user" value="${oracle.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${oracle.password}"/>
<property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
<property name="initialPoolSize" value="1"/>
<property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
<property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300"/>
<property name="maxStatements" value="0"/>
<property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000"/>
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
<property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 1 from dual" />
<property name="maxConnectionAge" value="14400" />
<property name="maxIdleTime" value="7200" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

I have set `maxConnectionAge` to 14400 (4hrs) and `maxIdleTime` to 7200 (2hr) so I was not expecting to see connection closed error as it should have destroyed the connection before 12 hours and new connection should be in-place.

Version details

- Mule Runtime - 4.3.0
- Oracle jdbc8 - 19.3.0.0
- c3p0 - 0.9.5.2

Can someone please advise if I am missing any configuration for c3p0 pooling ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the pool configuration. It might be a re-connection issue in the VPN, or even some limit in the database itself.

Comment: Hi Aled, Thanks for quick reply. Is there way to debug this issue by enabling logs for c3p0 to see what is happening ?  Is there any configuration I need enable for reconnection on c3p0 or mule database connector ?

Comment: I don't think so. Those are the configurations and Mule just use the datasource bean as a black box. C3p0 implements the pool. Enabling c3p0 logging might give you some messages but not sure if useful for troubleshooting this. If the issue is in infrastructure (example VPN) you will not see anything in the application.

Comment: How can I enable debug logs for c3p0? I suspected the maxConnectionAge and maxIdleTime not working or conflicting with other property as it should delete the connection after 4hr but it seems connection is still alive for longer and vpn or database closing it.

Comment: Are you sure you are consuming all queries? That should close the connections. For example using a for each scope after each query to ensure all results are consumed. Otherwise connections may be still open.

Comment: I have added debug logs and the error happens when c3p0 is testing connection every 5 mins. `DEBUG - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@62fd7c9 failed Connection test with an Exception! [query=select 1 from dual]`. If test query failing then real db query will also fail.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be checking out Connections, but not promptly checking them back in. c3p0 won't expire old Connections if they remain checked out, only after they have been checked in.

The "An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out" message suggests that eventually you've exhausted the Connection pool, there are no Connections left to check out and `maxPoolSize` has been reached.

When your application checks out Connections, it should use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct to ensure the Connection is promptly checked in after use.

Comment: As I am using mule database connector, I don’t do have option to control that so could this be a defect on mule side.

Comment: Even if the connection is not returned setting maxConnectionAge should trigger c3p0 to reclaim it, according to c3p0 documentation. And note that the question is about Mule applications using the Database connector. try-with-resources is for Java applications.

Comment: so, i don't know anything about mule, but i know a bit about c3p0. the c3p0 documentation says `maxConnectionAge` forces a Connection to be culled or purged *from the pool*. it is not reset by client checkouts (like `maxIdleTime` is), but it also won't close out connections beneath client applications, which have them already checked out.

Comment: the only c3p0 setting that will destroy connections checked out and in the custody of clients is [`unreturnedConnectionTimeout`](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout). since the issue seems to be that the application is checking out and holding, rather than promptly returning Connections, you might consider experimenting with [`unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients) to get a better understanding of what's going on.